# Problemas al crear redes virtuales en virt-manager

Tags: virtualización, gentoo

Quisiera consultaros sobre un problema relacionado con virt-manager y Qemu.
Estoy intentando usar este programa para crear una maquina virtual con Qemu desde Gentoo, pero tengo problemas para establecer la conexión de red.

Según he leído, para que las maquinas virtuales puedan usar la conexión de red del anfitrión, necesito crear una red virtual, la cual ira asociada a una interfaz del equipo anfitrión y se seleccionara como dispositivo asociado a la tarjeta de red de la maquina virtual.

Pero resulta que cuando intento crear una red virtual desde la ventana de "detalles", la opción de añadir redes me aparece desactivada[image: De esta forma]

He probado a activar las interfaces desde la pestaña de "network interfaces", pero me da este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Error setting interface startmode: esta función no está soportada por el controlador de conexión: virInterfaceDefineXML

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/host.py", line 788, in interface_apply
interface.set_startmode(newmode)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/interface.py", line 109, in set_startmode
self._redefine_xmlobj(xmlobj)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 389, in _redefine_xmlobj
self._define(newxml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/interface.py", line 44, in _define
return self.conn.define_interface(xml)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 684, in define_interface
return self._backend.interfaceDefineXML(xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3801, in interfaceDefineXML
if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virInterfaceDefineXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: esta función no está soportada por el controlador de conexión: virInterfaceDefineXML´
```

He seguido todos los pasos indicados en la wiki de Gentoo, activando todos los elementos del kernel que allí se indica, y cargando los módulos necesarios, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Incluso he probado a iniciar virt-manager con permisos de root, pero sin éxito

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:

Active estos flags al compilar libvirt: apparmor caps dbus libvirtd nls policykit qemu udev virt-network

Luego recompilé el kernel activando varias opciones que aparecían durante la compilación de libvirt, y reinicié.

Y ahora ya se me ha activado la opción para crear redes virtuales.

El segundo error permanece, pero la conexión funciona.